# Best Wi-Fi Performance Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: wi-fi, htc, network-signal, optimization

In wireless options there is such setup, but it does not do anything. It doesn't increase coverage or signal. And i think it does not consume more power.

Why? Because this option does not apply itself in my opinion. Maybe a bug?

Htc Desire S
Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 2):

Your phone settings cannot possibly affect the strength of the signal produced by a wireless router.

I would assume that this option just prevents Wi-Fi "sleep", seemingly confirmed by [this discussion](http://www.htcforums.com/desire-s/7828-wifi-not-working-properly.html).  If that's the case it **will** consume more power when you're not using your phone.

Comment: So it's either *Wi-Fi On* or *Wi-Fi* Off? Suppose i chose *Wi-Fi On*, does that mean Wi-Fi will always be active? It will consume more power but how much?  This option can save battery when talking to someone since you don't need to see anything, just to hear

Comment: ...him. But what i really would like to know is if there is no data exchange, Wi-Fi is still active and consumes power or it is active but **does not** consume power and not disconnects from internet.

Comment: @Boris_yo You're right, the screen uses more power than Wi-Fi.  If Wi-Fi is not sleeping it will consume power, even if there is no data transfer.  It uses even more power when there **is** data transfer, of course.  You have three options: Wi-Fi always on (enable it and enable Best Performance), Wi-Fi on when you use the device (enable it and disable Best Performance), or Wi-Fi off (disable Wi-Fi).

Comment: I would like 2nd option but the problem is that Wi-Fi goes to sleep when screen turns off. When that happens, trasnfer rate degrades significantly, Skype calls disconnect etc. What i would like is even when screen turns off Wi-Fi stays active but only when there are applications that use data or there is an active data transfer.